# Should we approve suggested edits that add a live example?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Recently came across [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3237586).

The edit added a link to fiddle that ran the query from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5096699) (as well as a dummy table/data from the original question).

Should this edit have been approved?

Answer (score 1):

> Should this edit have been approved?

No. If the anonymous user would want to have a link to a fiddle in the answer, he would have to create an account, gain the 'comment everywere' privilege, and add 'Can you add a link to a SQLFiddle please?' as a comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If the answer **is significantly clarified by it**, and it is easily established that it's indeed a demonstration of the answer in action, then I might accept it.

But not every such answer needs a live example. And I would certainly not advice any user to go to whatever random examples he can find and edit in such an item.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case I would vote to reject because:

1. The answer the fiddle was made for is neither the top-voted, nor the accepted answer
2. The question itself is from 2011

The only thing it has going for it is that it is in the top 400 questions by views for [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server). Even so, just adding a link to a fiddle given the above points, without adding any other value to the post, doesn't strike me as a great edit (or a needed edit) in this case.